# "{if item == ... " not parsing

Tags: parsing

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="games" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}
{game_platforms} 
    {if item == "PS3"}test{/if} 
    <span>{item}</span>
{/game_platforms} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I set this up in a testing template and oddly, the curly braces aren't even parsing, here's what I'm getting:

```
{if "PC" == "PS3"}PS3{/if} PC {if "PS3" == "PS3"}PS3{/if} PS3 {if "Xbox 360" == "PS3"}PS3{/if} Xbox 360
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What kind of field is `game_options`? What version of EE? Do other conditionals in other fields work?

Comment: What happens with {if "{item}" == ..... ?

Comment: @DerekHogue game_platforms is a checkbox field. Other conditionals seem to be working fine in the rest of the template, but within the {game_platforms} nothing is parsing, even {if username == "Jake"} won't work.

Comment: @Romans-8---31-39 Same issue occurs

Comment: What version of EE?

Comment: @DerekHogue 2.7.1

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug noted in EE2.5.3+ - https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18336 - I ran into this one myself.

It's been fixed as of EE2.7.2 - http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-7-2 (bug #19624)

Comment: Ah, thank you for your help. Do you know of any way to fix it without upgrading?

Comment: I don't think there was a fix, however if you use {game_platforms} 
    <span>{item}</span>
{/game_platforms} does that still output what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I do need the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this to work:

```
{if game_platforms == "PS3"}PS3{/if} 
{if game_platforms == "PC"}PC{/if} 
{if game_platforms == "XBOX"}XBOX{/if}
```